# How to use licensed version of flyway with dropwizard-flyway library

Tags: dropwizard, license-key

We are using the **dropwizard-flyway** library from https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard-flyway and want to use flyway Enterprise because we have **SQL Server 2012**. How can we get the license information into the **dropwizard-flyway** library?

We are trying out the trial version of flyway Enterprise and noticed that it installs its JARs into the maven repo **org\flywaydb\trial...**. Does this mean that we have to change our maven dependencies for flyway components from org.flywaydb.* to org.flywaydb.trial.* in order to use the trial version?

Comment: An enterprise edition should give you enterprise support. Why ask here?

Comment: Because I am on the trial version to try it out first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others who may run into the same issue, this is how I eventually fixed it:

1. Download and unzip the flyway enterprise trial version
2. Navigate to the directory you unzipped into
3. Run **installToLocalMavenRepo.cmd**
4. Run **deployToRemoteMavenRepo.cmd** - here you will need your remote repo **ID** and **URL**. I found these in my **distributionManagement** section in my projects **POM.XML** file.
5. In your project **POM.XML** file - add an exclusion for **flyway-core** to the **dropwizard-flyway** artifact as follows:

   ```
    <dependency>
       <groupId>io.dropwizard.modules</groupId>
       <artifactId>dropwizard-flyway</artifactId>
       <version>5.0.7</version>
       <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
             <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
             <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
       </exclusions>
    </dependency>
   ```
6. Add a dependency to **flyway-core** trial version as follows:

   ```
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.flywaydb.trial</groupId>
       <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
       <version>5.0.7</version>
    </dependency>
   ```

You should now be good to go.